# Eager Loading Throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I have the following code:

```
dbContext.TableATableB.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.TableA)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Options)
 .Where(x => x.TableAId ==15).ToList();
```

When executed, it throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning: An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Options'

So now every `TableA` has an `Options` (it's a one to many). All the ones with an `Options` seem to work, but the ones **without** `Options` fail.

I was expecting it to just be `null` or something that I could check for not an exception.

Comment: You cannot use "AsNoTracking" for lazy-loading. Can you post us TableATAbleB, TableA and Options models? Check if UseLazyLoadingProxies() and remove "virtual" from your navigation props

Comment: But I am not using lazy loading hence why I am using "Include"

Comment: EF would disagree. Even if you use "Include", EF is probably trying to lazy-load related data on other related navigation properties. Please check this link and read a bit, it's really useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: The thing is it does eager load it, I can see the query that it sends, it only does not seem to handle situations when there is no data to eager load.